# Why do Minecraft NPC's make door opening sounds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In 1.9 prereleases 2 and 3, the NPCs, f.k.a. Testificates, seem to make door opening sounds occasionally in the villages.

This does not appear to coincide with them moving through doorways, and I'm fairly sure that they don't open doors.

Has it been discussed or understood if anything is happening at the time, or is the sound just random?

Comment: Are you sure you are not hearing them trigger their tables? Which are just wooden pressure plates..

Comment: And are currently bugged to trigger when someone walks *next* to the pressure plate, instead of on it, to boot.

Comment: @James You should make that an answer. Even if it's not correct it's a damn good guess.

Comment: @James On reflection I think that is precisely what it is. Add it as an answer, and I'll mark you as correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tables in some of the homes are made from wooden pressure plates that the NPCs love to run into that can make this noise.

Answer (score -1):

Testificates, a.k.a. , Villagers, actually DO open doors. They open and close doors to leave the house during the daytime, and to enter it during the nighttime.

Comment: Is there a source that you could use to validate your answer?

Comment: @Texenox Its self evident that villagers open doors. Go hang out at a village near dusk or dawn.